# How do read the last character per string?

Tags: javascript

[image]

My code generates a string, as shown in the image. At the end of each line a number in euros is shown, let call these euros1 and euros2. The idea is that the amount ✓ icons is multiplied with euros1 and euros2 shown per line. So in the case of my example: (10,45 + 5,50) x 2 = 31,90 for the first line, and for the second line (18,24 + 9,60) x 3 = 83,52. These numbers are supposed to be combined to a total of 115,42.

However my current code produces a total of 218,95. So it takes the sum of all the euros1 and euros2 and multiplies it by the total amount of ✓ icons.

How can I calculate the sum of the euros1 + euros2 x the amount ✓ icons, per line?

I think a for loop could help me, however I am new to Javascript and I am not sure how to proceed.

```
var temp = g_form.getValue('mwadm_onkosten_list_refList_changes');
var count = (temp.match(/✓/g) || []).length;

var lastChar = temp[temp.length -1];
if (count != temp);
{
    total = total * count;
}
```

Comment: Your image isn't showing...

Comment: Your data should be inside your question (as text), not an image, and we need the raw input data as in `temp`.

Comment: Hi, could you please add the data as text to your question ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of a split solution just like @dganenco mentioned. I created a TEMP variable to reproduce your result string. And execute a function on it foreach row.

And i intentionally kept it really simple. Hope this helps.

```
var temp = ["✓|| €10,45 | €1,50 ", "✓|| €10,45 | €2,50 ", "✓|| €10,45 | €3,50 "];
var totalTimes = (String(temp).match(/✓/g) || []).length;

//perform function for each row
temp.forEach(CalculateRow);

//Splits the row, Gets euro1 as decimal, euro2 as decimal, calculates the amount a character is found, calculates total, prints it to console.
function CalculateRow(item, index) {
    var arr = item.split('|');
    var euro1 = GetValueFromArray(arr,1);
    var euro2 = GetValueFromArray(arr, 2);
    var times = (String(arr).match(/✓/g) || []).length;
    var _total = (euro1 + euro2) * times;
    console.log(_total);
}

//Takes the index value, and casts it to decimal value
function GetValueFromArray(arr, index){
    var getindex = arr.length -index;
    var result = arr[getindex];
    result = result.replace('€', '');
    return parseFloat(result, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution for you in case if is it possible to only split strings by `|` symbol, then get last 2 values and do all needed stuff using them.

```js
const strArr = ['asd|addf|$56.60|$10.40', 'asd|addf|$5.60|$1.40'];
let sum = 0;
strArr.forEach(str => {
 const splitted = str.split('|');
 debugger;
 const x = getNumber(splitted[splitted.length - 2]);
 const y = getNumber(splitted[splitted.length - 1]);
 sum += (x+y)*2;
});

function getNumber(str){
 return +str.substring(1);
}

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `temp` is the multiline string in the form of
`asd|√|√| €12.34 | €15.25
  zxc|√|| €18.34 | €19.25`
This code should give you a sum of last two numbers multiplied by the amount of √

```js
var temp = "asd|√|√| €12.34 | €15.25\nzxc|√|| €18.34 | €19.25"
let lines = temp.split('\n')
let linesSummaries = []
for(let line of lines){
 var count = line.match(/√/g).length
 var vars = line.split('|')
 var x = parseFloat(vars[vars.length-1].match(/\d+\.?\d*/))
 var y = parseFloat(vars[vars.length-2].match(/\d+\.?\d*/))
 var lineSum = (x + y ) * count 
 linesSummaries.push(lineSum)
}
console.log(linesSummaries)
```